# Rotate an Image pivot in the Center - Android

Tags: android, image, rotation

I want to rotate an Image pivoting in the center. I  want to use this when i rotate the image I need to load dynamic Text as menu. Like a Jog. Any one pls help me for rotating an image

Answer (score 31):

To rotate an image you can do this:

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

ImageView image = findViewById(my image);
image.setAnimation(rotate);

rotate.start();
```

This will rotate the image one round from 0 to 360 degrees. You can set the duration too:

```
rotate.setDuration( 500 ); // milliseconds
```

Comment: but the image in the background (containing the imageview is not rotating.. ) :)
and help on this :=) ?

Comment: You need to set the image as the `src` of the `ImageView`, not as the `background`

Comment: I have set as src but not rotating, can you help please ?

Comment: Use image.startAnimation(rotate)  instead of rotate.start().